# Has anyone tried to repurpose their discarded AWS DeepLens?

Tags: aws-deeplens

I managed to install Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm having trouble establishing the connection with the camera. I'm also having difficulties installing the awscam library. My idea is to use the lens as a sort of Blaspberry. Any suggestions besides Amazon's recommendation to recycle my device?